Why does an SSD with Windows 10 not boot from particular SATA port, boots from USB and in other PC?
I have a Dell Latitude E5440 with a SATA Samsung EVO 870 that has Windows 10 installed on it, and it doesn't boot from the SATA port (other Windows 10 SATA SSDs boot without issue).

It does boot when connected to a SATA-to-USB adapter, as well as on another computer’s SATA and USB port
I can only enter the UEFI firmware menu when the 870 EVO isn't connected
As much as I can understand, Windows 10 installation on SSD works but the laptop and SSD don't work together

Any thoughts?
UPDATE
When I turn on the computer with SSD connected to SATA port, I see Dell logo and then following text: "Initializing Intel(R) Boot Agent GE v1.5.38.01 PXE 2.1 Build 092 (WfM 2.0)" so I guess it's trying for network boot.
If I press F2 or F12 to enter UEFI settings or Boot menu yellow text appears in upper right corner, but then dissappears and process reaches to the same place as before.
If I start computer without any disk says "No bootable device found ..." and I can enter setup with F2.
In UEFI under System Configuration -> Integrated NIC I change "Enabled w/PXE" to "Enabled".
If I start computer now, it ends with black sceen and cursor blinking in upper left corner.
Same things happen whether I choose Legacy or UEFI Boot List Option.
UPDATE 2
After updating BIOS from A01 to A24 the computer boots to win10 from EVO 870 SSD.

It has UEFI firmware, not BIOS (these are not the same things), so it sounds like the SSD was configured for BIOS and isn’t configured for EFI boot. If that’s the case, either boot another Windows install/WinRE/WinPE and use Mbr2Gpt to convert the drive to GPT, and the correct partition GUIDs. I don’t recall if it also adds in the EFI boot files onto the EFI partition, but if not, use BcdBoot C:\Windows /s Z: /f UEFI to do so (Z: EFI partition). If that’s not the issue, has the following been run from WinRE/WinPE: BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /RebuildBCD

What precisely occurs when trying to boot the 870 EVO via the SATA port? Is it failing POST? When installing the SATA cable, has its seating been double checked?

It's a very old model indeed, unlike the ones mentioned in my now deleted answer. According to this it supports SATA II (3Gb/s = SATA II) and the drive you're trying to use is SATA III (and SSD). Although this usually isn't a problem it may need a firmware update to accept the newer and definitive version. In any case it seems a waste of money using such expensive SSD.

@ChanganAuto: I'd be very surprised if that were the problem, given that the OS doesn't speak either of those protocols – the SATA controller does – and generally they are backwards-compatible both ways. (Not necessarily a waste though; flash storage even with SATA II will leave typical 5400 rpm laptop HDDs in the dust. I've upgraded an IDE laptop to an SSD and it was still worth it.)

@grawity_u1686 The reason I said what I said is because, according to the OP, "I can only enter the UEFI firmware menu when the 870 EVO isn't connected". This has nothing to do with the OS indeed. The aforementioned firmware update was UEFI but on a second look the drive's firmware might need an update too. And I wasn't criticizing the upgrade to a SSD - I've done many - just the choice of an obscenely expensive one.
